# How to replace an answer if a condition is met

Tags: mysql

I am looking at how I can write a my sql query that replaces an answer when a condition is met. In this case we have members who can say no to the question "Do you want other members to see your email address?" the following query lists all members and their email addresses and also the answer to the question, I need to replace the email address of those who say No with a message "Not For Publication or similar"

```
select josvy_osmembership_subscribers.`id`as ID,
    concat (`first_name`," ",`last_name`) as name,
    josvy_osmembership_field_value.`field_value` as Answer,
    `email`AS Email,
    `plan_id`AS plan,
    `plan_subscription_status` as status,
    josvy_osmembership_field_value.field_id as Field_id
from `josvy_osmembership_subscribers`,
    `josvy_osmembership_field_value`
where josvy_osmembership_subscribers.id = josvy_osmembership_field_value.Subscriber_Id
    and plan_id = 1
    and plan_subscription_status = 1
    and josvy_osmembership_field_value.`field_id` = 16
order by ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query to hide email addresses of members who answered as `No`

```
SELECT 
  s.`id` AS ID,
  CONCAT(`first_name`, " ", `last_name`) AS NAME,
  v.`field_value` AS Answer,
  CASE
    WHEN v.`field_value` = 'No' 
    THEN 'Not For Publication or similar'
    ELSE `email` 
  END AS Email,
  `plan_id` AS Plan,
  `plan_subscription_status` AS STATUS,
  v.field_id AS Field_id 
FROM
  `josvy_osmembership_subscribers` s
  JOIN `josvy_osmembership_field_value` v 
    ON s.id = v.Subscriber_Id 
WHERE plan_id = 1 
  AND plan_subscription_status = 1 
  AND v.`field_id` = 16 
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: @ric i have updated my answer try the updated query it shoudl work fine

Comment: it also now gets the expected result thanks but also shows some errors in the query panel

Comment: @ric what errors can you please provide error details

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` expression to select the email or the *message* conditionally based on the value of the answer.

```
select s.id as id,
    concat (first_name, ' ', last_name) as name,
    v.field_value as answer,
    case when v.field_value = 'No' then 'Not For Publication or similar' else email end as email,
    plan_id as plan,
    plan_subscription_status as status,
    v.field_id as field_id
from josvy_osmembership_subscribers s
join josvy_osmembership_field_value v on s.id = v.subscriber_id
where plan_id = 1
    and plan_subscription_status = 1
    and v.field_id = 16
order by id
```

Also, always use explicit join syntax instead of old comma based joins and try to alias the table to cleanup your queries instead of using the whole table name everywhere.

Comment: sorry but this creates the following error  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN `josvy_osmembership_field_value` v 
    ON s.id = v.Subscriber_Id

Comment: @ric you should be getting this error from my answer, I have updated the answer check updated version

Comment: @ric - My query seems fine. can you share the screenshot of the query and error you got. If you can reproduce the error on rextester.com, that'll be better.

Comment: OK now it gets the expected result but still shows some errors in the query panel, How do I post a screen shot in here?

Comment: Put it on some other site and post the link here

Comment: @ric what do you mean result OK and error in query panel? Do you mean warnings? If so, disregard them as long as the query works.

Comment: @ric that is totally fine. The query is OK. The query panel is buggy.